# how to understand variables setting in below makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, settings

```
OS := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
   ext = o
   cmd = build.sh
else
   ext = exe
   cmd = build.bat
endif

serverNM := server.$(ext)
clientNM := client.$(ext)
programs := $(serverNM) $(clientNM)

$(serverNM) libs = priv protocol $(wildcard *.conf)
$(serverNM) objs = server impl.$(ext) server access.$(ext)
$(clientNM) objs = client impl.$(ext) client api.$(ext)
$(clientNM) libs = protocol

all: $(programs)

define ProgramTmp =
$(1): $$($(1) objs) $$($(1) libs)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(programs),$(eval $(call ProgramTmp,$(prog))))

$(programs):
    $(cmd) $@ $^

%.conf : %.$(ext)
    genConf $^ -o $@

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
   demo.o : demo.c linux.conf 
        install $^ -o $@
else
   demo.exe : demo.c win.conf
        install.bat $^ -o $@
endef
```

how to understand the     "$(serverNM) libs = priv protocol $(wildcard *.conf)"
why before libs there is still variable $(serverNM)?
does it means set the two together?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of GNU make a setting like this:

```
ext = o

serverNM := server.$(ext)

$(serverNM) libs = priv protocol $(wildcard *.conf)
```

will set the make variable `server.o libs` (yes, the name of the variable contains whitespace) and then a reference like this:

```
$(server.o libs)
```

expands to the value of that variable.

In newer versions of GNU make, this makefile contains syntax errors because variable names containing whitespace were made illegal in GNU make 3.82 (released in July 2010).